# vmware virtualized intel vt-x/ept requires a preferred mode of Intel VT-x/ept reverting to automatic?

Tags: vmware, mode, reverting

Window System 7x64 SP1
VM Workstation 11

When virtualization engine preferred mode is explicitly enabled with `Intel VT-x or AMD-V`, the following message is displayed during boot of the VM:

> "vmware virtualized intel vt-x/ept requires a preferred mode of Intel
>   VT-x/ept reverting to automatic?"

The Intel Processor Identification Utility (PIU) reports Virtualization technologies capabilities. In the BIOS, it does not have an option to explicitly enable VT-x.

Q: Does the PIU test indicate the VT-x is enabled implicitly in the BIOS

When booting with virtualization engine preferred mode is explicitly enabled with Automatic. The settings appear with both virtualize VT-x/EPT and CPU performance grayed out:

When booting with virtualization engine preferred mode is explicitly enabled with `Automatic`.  The settings appear with both `virtualize VT-x/EPT` and `CPU performance` grayed out:

Q: I am uncertain what this means?

Q: Is there a way (a service, process, etc) to determine if Virtualization technologies are being enabled for the VM?